# How to Read and write into/from a text file?

Tags: windows, mfc, atl

Please correct the below code:only.

file already contains entries : 1st row username; 2nd row password.

checkbox status required to write to the third line and need to read or alter only the checkbox status value in the file.

Currently this code is working if there already is a value for the checkbox status value, then it is overwriting, else UI is hanging.

```
WriteCheckStatusToFile(BOOL& locVar)
{
    FILE *l_pFile = NULL;
    CString l_strRememberCheck;
    l_strRememberCheck = GetExePath() + _T("password");

    CString sVar;
    sVar.Format(_T("%d"),locVar);
    if(NULL != (l_pFile = fopen(l_strRememberCheck, _T("r+"))) )
    {
        int count = 0;
        char c;
        while(count != 2)
        {
            if((c = fgetc(l_pFile)) == '\n') count++;
        }
        fseek(l_pFile,ftell(l_pFile),SEEK_SET);
        fprintf(l_pFile, sVar);
    }
    l_strRememberCheck.ReleaseBuffer();
    fclose(l_pFile);
}
```

thanks in advance to all!
sam.

Comment: `sVar` doesn't look like C-string.

Comment: What language is this? How are `BOOL` and `CString` defined?

Comment: `C++` and `C` are very different languages, and both tags cannot apply. Please only use the proper tag for your questions, and don't just randomly pick them.

Comment: @epsalon This is Windows code, either under MFC or ATL. CString comes with both these days.

Comment: Try the following (a): checking for EOF on that inner while loop may be wise, and (b) running your code in a debugger. There are literally not enough lines of code in this function to NOT catch the reason why it isn't behaving as you desire. I can promise you most people on SO will take as much initiative to help solve your problems as you do.

Comment: @fasked The `C` in `CString` stands for "class" (Hungarian Notation). All classes in MFC and ATL start with C.

Comment: @user1610015 `CString` is MFC-class of course, C-String is null-terminated array of char. The `fprintf` function doesn't know anything about `CString` class. It can take only C-String (array). I've tried to mark error.

Comment: @fasked: +1 for staring at this long enough to to see that (39 minutes ago, in fact).

Comment: Awww @Walter. he used a CString in there. incorrectly, but he still used it. should count for *something* =P

Comment: `CString` actually works with printf/fprintf, because it contains only a char pointer. This use is supported by MFC (originally by accident).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line

```
fprintf(l_pFile, sVar);
```

doesn't look right. I think it should be

```
fprintf(l_pFile, "%s\n", (LPCTSTR) sVar);
```

The loop could become infinite if the file has less than two linefeeds:

```
while(count != 2)
```

I think it should be:

```
while( (count < 2) && ( ! feof(l_pFile) ) && ( c != EOF ) )
```

Probably unrelated to your error, but - at least for this code snippet -  CString::ReleaseBuffer() doesn't need to be called since you have not called CString::GetBuffer().

```
l_strRememberCheck.ReleaseBuffer();
```

This line may be unnecessary as it appears to fseek() to where the file pointer already is:

```
fseek(l_pFile,ftell(l_pFile),SEEK_SET);
```

In the event a two-line file is not terminated with a '\n' you would need to print like this:

```
   if ( count == 2 )
   {
      fprintf(l_pFile, "%s\n", (LPCTSTR) sVar);
   }
   else
   {
      fprintf(l_pFile, "\n%s\n", (LPCTSTR) sVar);
   }
```

Comment: I did changes in the code as you suggested, but the checkbox status is always adding in the 2nd line, so that password is not matching. it is required to add in third line of the text file. Please check the logic again.

Comment: My suspicion is that when you have a two-line file, the second line is not terminated with a '\n'. You can add this if to wrap your fprintf: if ( count == 2 ) fprintf(l_pFile,"%s\n",sVar); else fprintf(l_pFile,"\n%s\n",sVar);

Comment: forgot the (LPCTSTR). Correction is above in the answer.